Is there a textbook that covers probability from the linear algebra perspective?
When I first studied probability, I learned the concepts of single RV $X$, two RVs $(X, Y)$ and vector of RVs $(X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_N)$.
Somehow I never made the connection between RV and linear algebra.
I guess the reasons are:

Notation. $(X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_N)$ is not the standard notation for vector. Also so much time is spent on learning single RV, which are uninteresting from the linear algebra perspective.
Meaning of entries. Each $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are functions, where in linear algebra we work with real or complex numbers.
Matrices. My textbook stopped at vector of RVs. But in linear algebra we routinely work with matrices. I have never seen matrices of RVs.

In any case, now I run into trouble because I'm studying machine learning and data (which are high dimensional vectors) are assumed to be RVs and have distribution. The weights (in the billions, can be represented as matrices or what not) are also RVs and have distribution. Then there is sampling of random vectors which are not jointly Gaussian. There is also sum of random variables, which is nothing but a dot product between random variables and the one vector.
I feel that perhaps what is needed for me is to study probability from a more linear algebra perspective, as linear algebra routinely deal with higher dimensional objects. Does anyone have recommendations in this regard?


What is  so puzzling about that notation and the fact that $X_i$ are functions? What you wrote is a random vector. 2. If we make the real or complex numbers we work with in linear algebra functions of something you don't have to revolutionise the theory. Just fix the argument your functions are eating and proceed as usual. 3. Pick four random variables and arrange them in a $2\times 2$-matrix instead of a vector. Do you see the matrix of RVs now?


@KurtG. to 1. That notation is non-standard. The standard way is a column vector. The difference is not huge but nevertheless confusing for a first-year student, to 3. It is a matrix of RV, but from the probability perspective how do we proceed to define the PMF, PDF, conditional distribution, Bayes' theorem, etc. of a matrix of RV., and from the linear algebra perspective what is the meaning of the inverse, the eigenvalue-eigenvector, the determinant, the norm, the inner product?


We hopefully agree now that we don't need a textbook to learn that notation. 3. Those multiple questions should be asked in a specific post. You will learn more from crunching some explicit examples.


You might want to check this text:
High-Dimensional Probability-An Introduction with Applications in Data Science by Roman Vershynin.

Who is this book for?
This is a textbook in probability in high dimensions with a view toward applications in data sciences. It is intended for doctoral and advanced masters students and beginning researchers in mathematics, statistics, electrical engineering, computer science, computational biology and related areas, who are looking to expand their knowledge of theoretical methods used in modern research in data sciences.

ref: https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html
